# Can the head of a list ever represent more than one value

Tags: haskell, recursion

If I call the function `interleave` (defined below - it's a function to insert a number (or any type) at each position of a list) like this the resulting lists are all the same length

```
interleave 1 [2,3,4]
[[1,2,3,4],[2,1,3,4],[2,3,1,4],[2,3,4,1]]
```

However, I expected  the list lengths to be increasingly shorter because the recursive call to `interleave` passes the list minus the head (i.e only `ys`). Since the tail of the list keeps getting shorter with each call, I expect the resulting lists to be shorter.

```
interleave :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
interleave x []     = [[x]]
interleave x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : map (y:) (interleave x ys)
```

How do the lists end up being the same length if the list argument to the recursive call is increasingly shorter?

The only answer I can imagine is that the mapped value `map (y:)` represents more than one digit in the recursive calls (i.e. it's the 2 in [2,1,3,4] and the `2,3` in [2,3,1,4] and the `2,3,4` in [2,3,4,1]` but I'm not sure if that's possible and I don't know how to log values during the execution in haskell.

Question, in other words, can `y` (the head of the list) represent more than a single value in the recursive calls?

In answering the question (if it's relevant), please confirm/explain if the `(x:y:ys)` in `(x:y:ys) : map (y:) (interleave x ys)` only ever represents one list (i.e. it is the [1,2,3,4- with the integer argument inserted in the first position).

(It might help if you could show the execution order of the func, or how the values get stored on the stack)

Comment: Note, I had difficulty deciding on the right question to ask. Please let me know if the question should be posed differently.

Comment: Having seen a lot of badly-posed questions, let me reassure you: you've done a great job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list lengths of the recursive calls are indeed progressively shorter; however, the function modifies the results from the recursive calls to lengthen them. Let's build up from the bottom. For empty lists, nothing interesting happens:

```
interleave 1 []
= { first clause of definition }
[[1]]
```

But by the time we get to a list with one element, we already see the interesting thing happening. Specifically, since the result of the recursive call is passed to `map (y:)`, the short lists produced by the recursive call are each expanded by one element.

```
interleave 1 [4]
= { list syntax }
interleave 1 (4:[])
= { second clause of definition }
(1:4:[]) : map (4:) (interleave 1 [])
= { recursive call, which produces short answers }
(1:4:[]) : map (4:) [[1]]
= { definition of map, which lengthens each answer }
(1:4:[]) : [4:[1]]
= { list syntax }
[[1,4],[4,1]]
```

In a similar way, `interleave 1 [3,4]` makes the recursive call `interleave 1 [4]` to produce `[[1,4],[4,1]]`, but then uses `map (3:)` to lengthen each element of that to `[[3,1,4],[3,4,1]]`.

Addressing your direct questions in turn now:

> How do the lists end up being the same length if the list argument to the recursive call is increasingly shorter?

Each time a recursive call on a shorter list is made, the results of the recursive call are made longer -- these are exactly balanced out so that calling `interleave` with a length-`n` list will result in a collection of length-`n+1` lists.

> can `y` (the head of the list) represent more than a single value in the recursive calls?

No, the head of a list is always a single value. The real magic is that each recursive call is adding onto the head -- so you can get many extra heads from many recursive calls.

> confirm/explain if the `(x:y:ys)` in `(x:y:ys) : map (y:) (interleave x ys)` only ever represents one list (i.e. it is the `[1,2,3,4-` with the integer argument inserted in the first position).

Correct.

Comment: This still confuses me: `Each time a recursive call on a shorter list is made, the results of the recursive call are made longer -- these are exactly balanced out so that calling interleave with a length-n list will result in a collection of length-n+1 lists.`  For example, if (in the example from the op) the tail `ys` is simply [4] (as it will be at the end), and only one value is mapped over the list `(y:)`, I still don't understand how the final list can be four values long. Are the progressively longer results of the recursive call represented by a value in the func?

Comment: @Leahcim The call `interleave 1 [2,3,4]` (call this A) calls `interleave 1 [3,4]` (B), which calls `interleave 1 [4]` (C), which calls `interleave 1 []` (D). D returns lists of length 1; then C prepends an element to each of these lists before returning, so C returns lists of length 2. Then B prepends an element to each of the lists produced by C, so B returns lists of length 3. Then A prepends an element to each of the lists produced by B, so A returns lists of length 4. In other words: it is *not* the case that only one value is prepended, although *each call* prepends only one (more) value.

Comment: Thank you, that comment helps a lot and I accepted your answer already. One thing that's still unclear ( for you or anyone  else to answer if time) is how D, being the final call, returns 'lists'  ( i.e. Why does it return more than one list?). From what I understand from your answer is that the number of lists returned from each call will equal number of calls to interleave ( it's length of each list that changes) but how are four lists of length 1 returned from interleave 1 []? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Leahcim Actually, both the lists themselves and the list of lists is extended by one in each recursive call. In `(x:y:ys) : map (y:) (...)`, the `map` extends each list returned by a recursive call, then the `(x:y:ys) : ...` adds an additional list to the list of lists. So `interleave 1 []` returns a list of lists with just one list in it, and the remaining calls add in the remaining lists.